# Bootstrap will not resize properly on my phone, but will on desktop

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

This is my first legit website I'm working on and I can't get this simple thing to work. Here is the code on pastebin:

https://pastebin.com/CEU74Fx6

Here is some code to bypass the error notification.

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="intro">
```

(I am so sorry for linking pastebin but it is a lot of code. Please understand that trying to format it here was way to time-consuming and pastebin highlights HTML elements anyways).

On my desktop bootstrap works perfectly and resizes as it should. Here is a short video of how it resizes correctly.

https://streamable.com/pynkm

In regular view mode (the first part of the video) the elements are aligned correctly. When I go into responsive design mode, the elements also align correctly.

But when I upload the website to my server, and test it out on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge), the elements align incorrectly.

Android Firefox:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSnya.png

Android Chrome:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP5Ro.png

As you can see, the elements align as if they were in the phone browsers desktop view mode (it's not in desktop view mode).

I tried this on someone else's phone and the same thing happened.

Is this a bootstrap bug? Is my code wrong?

Comment: Do you have this in your base html page? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: To post the code here you just click the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon. That's the right way to do it.

Comment: Looking at the code, and imagining the column sizes in `sm` and `xs`, I think the display is correct

Comment: post your code and tell example output.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

with this one:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

That should tell your phone not to shrink-fit.

Another mistake I see there: You seem to be using Bootstrap rows without a container. Bootstrap rows always need a `.container` or a `.container-fluid` around them to work properly.

Comment: You need to clear the cache of your browsers after applying the changes.

Comment: Found the solution. The problem was the mozilla dev tools resolution for the Galaxy s7 edge is actually larger than the actual resolution on my phone (even though I have it at the lowest resolution to save power). using col-lg-# is what fixed it.